# How do I use Bash to tell Java to run a .jar program in a specific Linux directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, java, jar

I am trying to write a Bash script to (amongst other things) run a particular Java programme stored in a .jar file.

The script is in a directory we will call `foo`. It includes this line

```bsh
java -jar ~/Simutrans-Extended/simutrans-extended/Nightly-Updater-V2.jar -cl
```

When I run the script, the .jar file executes as though it were running in `foo`. But I need it to be executed in its actual location, in this case `~/Simutrans-Extended/simutrans-extended/`. How do I do this please?

The script is running on Ubuntu 20.04, should that be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cd` to change the directory in the line before the command. So the Bash script now reads:

```bsh
cd ~/Simutrans-Extended/simutrans-extended/ && java -jar ./Nightly-Updater-V2.jar -cl
```

Comment: I suggest to use `cd ... && java ...` or `cd ... || exit 1` to ensure that your java program is only called if no problem occurred when switching to destination directory.

Comment: I am using Windows, and if I want to run a .jar file, the commands I use will almost exactly the same syntax as the above mentioned commands, just all slashes will be backslashes, the commands seem to be universal...

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you, that is a really helpful tip! I have added it to the answer.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς I am learning Linux from a Windows background too. While I agree they are conveniently similar, I believe there are two important differences. Windows does not accept `~` to refer to the user's home directory and the `.` is not necessary to refer to the present working directory. So it's best to keep this answer as Linux-only.

Comment: How did you managed to post the Q and the A at ~~.~~.37Z ? Surely *answer own question*?